# how to ignore/retain non html tag in tinymce editor inside blogengine

Tags: editor, tinymce

I am using tinyMce in blogengine 1.6.I want to retain the tag  for comments when I switch between raw view to html view.But it tags disappear when I am switching with check box click.
Please suggest how can I retain these tags in textbox content.

Thanks 
Ritu

Answer (score 0):

You need to define these tags as valid tags in your tinymce init, i.e.:

```
extended_valid_elements : 'mycustomelement',
custom_elements : 'mycustomelement',
```

You should also have [a closer look at how this parameter is set.](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/custom_elements)